# AWS EC Security group can not connect from internal network

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

I created 3 intances in same VPC and same subnet.

2 instances A,B use same security group: **WebSG** (id: ***sg-ab***)

instance C use security group: **DbSG** (id: ***sg-onlyc***)

In WebSG, I add rule Alltraffic from source: sg-ab

In DbSG, I add rule: mysql from source: sg-ab

On A and B are unable to connect to mysql on C. A,B are unable to connect to each other.

I could ssh/https to 3 instances from my home.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are they trying to connect to external IP addresses?

Comment: I just tried ping to external IP, it did not work :(

Comment: Check out my answer to this question https://serverfault.com/questions/993595/aws-ec2-ssh-security-group-inbound-rules-do-not-work/993707#993707